# Get image URL that is inside a <li> that is inside an array of jQuery selector items

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, selector

I am using a jQuery image slider plugin in which I am trying to get the Image URL of the current image when a button is clicked.

The way the slider works is that it shows all the images slides which are list items in 1 continuous horizontal row and it simply updates the CSS position when it changes to show the next or previous slide so there are no classes or anything added to the current slide to indicate which slide is shown.

I do however have access to the array number of the current slide.

I then also have access to the variable holding the list of slides as a jQuery selector object....

```
var $slides = $slider.children('li');
```

The above selector variable holds an array collection of `li` list items which have an image inside each one.

So my goal is to take the variable `$slides` and pluck out the image from the item with with array key 1 just as an example....

So how could I get the 2nd array item with key 1 and then select the image inside that items `<li>` element?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has 2 functions that return an element by index.

`get(index)` returns the DOM element from the selection with the given index

`eq(index)` returns the DOM element wrapped as jquery element

```
var $slides = $slider.children('li');
var imgSrc = $slides.eq(index).find('img').attr('src');
```